# Convert database query results to excel and allow download from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have looked through a few similar questions but can't quite find what I am looking for (please don't mark this as duplicate as I did try to find an answer without posting a question)

When the user clicks on a button, an ajax request is sent to the controller where I am getting data back from the model. I am then converting it to a csv format and on success of the ajax call I want the file to download. I have everything working except the download part. I have seen some examples where you just redirect but that doesn't download anything, it shows a new page with the results.

```
$( '.spExcel' ).on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + '/Widgets/exportSpExcel',
        type: 'POST',
    })

    .done(function (data) {
        window.location.assign(data);

    })
});
```

PHP:

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {


        $results = $this->DashboardModel->listPeople();
        $filename = 'People_' . date('dmY') . '.csv'; 

        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        $header = array("Name", "Contact Number"); 
        fputcsv($handle, $header);      

        foreach ($results as $result):
            fputcsv($handle, $result);
        endforeach;

        fclose($handle);

    }
```

Comment: its not downloading the csv file?

Comment: @suresh, nope. Not download the file unfortunately.

Comment: There's no need to use ajax for this.  If you want to download the file just use `window.open(url + '/Widgets/exportSpExcel', '_blank');`  That will either work or give an indication of why it doesn't.

Comment: did you include your library class

Comment: @Archer, thanks for that. It works! But the page jumps like it is refreshing. I don't want that to happen which is why I wanted to do it with ajax

Comment: *"it shows a new page with the results"* - this is browser choice.   You can configure your browser to always download certain file types or to show them in the browser.  You can't *control* this, you can *suggest* it with `content-disposition:inline=false`

Comment: Glad that worked - you now know the server-side code is fine.  Your problem is that you can't write files yourself - the browser *has* to do it for you.  You could just change the clickable element to a link, set the `href` value to the Url to download the file and add the download attribute -> `<a href="/Widgets/exportSpExcel" download>click to download</a>`

Comment: @Archer, that has simplified things significantly and the page doesn't refresh. Perfect! Please could you make that your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped - will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax isn't capable of writing a downloaded file - the browser *has* to do that itself.  You could use `window.open()` but that would open the file in a new tab or window, which would then close immediately.  That can look messy - it works but isn't ideal.

The simplest way to deal with this is to make the link download the response directly, without trying to use Ajax.  Change the link to suit your needs, but it would be something like this...

```
<a href="/Widgets/exportSpExcel" class="spExcel" download>click to download</a>
```

Just add the `download` attribute to a link.  It really is that simple :)

Comment: Thank you! Brilliantly easy solution.

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)